# Helm's v3 Example Doesn't Show Multi-line Properties. Get YAML to JSON parse error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

In Helm's v3 documentation: [Accessing Files Inside Templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/), the author gives an example of 3 properties (toml) files; where each file has only one key/value pair.

The configmap.yaml looks like this. I'm only adding one *config.toml* for simplicity.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-config
data:
  {{- $files := .Files }}
  {{- range tuple "config.toml" }}
  {{ . }}: |-
    {{ $files.Get . }}
  {{- end }}
```

This works fine, until I add a *second* line to the config.toml file.

config.toml

```
replicaCount=1
foo=bar
```

Then I get an Error: `INSTALLATION FAILED: YAML parse error on deploy/templates/configmap.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 9: could not find expected ':'`

Any thoughts will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Helm will read in that file, but it is (for good or bad) a **text** templating engine. It does not understand that you are trying to compose a YAML file and thus it will not help you. That's actually why you will see so many, many templates in the wild with `{{ .thing | indent 8 }}` or `{{ .otherThing | toYaml }}` -- because [you need to help Helm](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#controlling-whitespace) know in what context it is emitting the *text*

Thus, in your specific case, you'll want the [`indent` filter](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/strings.html#indent) with a value of 4 because your current template has two spaces for the key indent level, and two more spaces for the value block scalar

```
data:
  {{- $files := .Files }}
  {{- range tuple "config.toml" }}
  {{ . }}: |-
{{ $files.Get . | indent 4 }}
{{/* notice this ^^^ template expression is flush left,
because the 'indent' is handling whitespace, not the golang template itself */}}
  {{- end }}
```

---

Also, while this is the specific answer to your question, don't overlook the [`.AsConfig` section on that page](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/#configmap-and-secrets-utility-functions) which seems much more likely to be what you really want to happen, and requires less `indent` math

Comment: Thanks, this worked! It's odd to me that Helm won't print out the failed YAML as text for debugging; would be helpful. Not a fan so far. By the way, I'm trying to access config files outside of the chart, do you know if that's possible?

Comment: No, it cannot access files outside the chart directory, nor any file glob referenced in `.helmignore`, nor any file within the `templates` directory. As for the "print out the failure," at least as of helm 3.7.2, including `--debug` in `helm template` does render the offensive text, although regrettably also with a huge golang backtrace